# How to reuse a custom designed window in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a custom designed window as shown below.

[Custom Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y7vC.jpg)

The following is my XAML design with the styles omitted for simplicity.

```
<Window x:Class="CustomWindowBase.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomWindowBase"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="CustomWindow" Height="600" Width="870" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
            ResizeMode="NoResize" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent">
    <Border Style="{StaticResource MainWindowBorderStyle}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="590*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Border Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource TitleBarBorderStyle}">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleStyle}" Text="Custom Window"/>
                    <Button x:Name="BtnClose" Style="{StaticResource CloseButtonStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>

            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <!-- Different User Control Here -->
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

There's two events for the code behind of this window that supports the close/drag action.

How can I reuse this shell for every other window that my application will potentially open, sort of like a base class that can be inherited?

If at all possible, I wouldn't want to do much in the code behind, like instantiating an instance of this window shell and assigning it's content with another user control.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the XAML stuff in a `ControlTemplate`.

For the `<!-- Different User Control Here -->` part, insert a `<ContentPresenter />`. It knows what to do. *It just knows.*

Apply the template, and the other desired property values, with a `Style`.

Comment: Wow, that content presenter is some magic! This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for your help, marked as answer.

For the events, I implemented the Close and Drag in my App.xaml.cs, by casting the sender to their controls and doing Window.GetWindow() instance and calling the Close and DragMove methods.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, then it's fine. Call it from outside the window with

`new MainWindow().ShowDialog();`

Comment: No, sorry, I meant having the same look and feel for all other windows that I might create and use. Not opening them..